# Dockerfile missing packages

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have the following dockerfile, that works fine for building and running through Visual Studio:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

The problem is that when I try to run docker build in the directory that hosts the .csproj, I am missing references to local .dll packages.

I get that I need to use a dockerfile COPY to get the packages into the container, but when I tried that with the line:

```
COPY C:/path/to/packages/*.dll .
```

just above the RUN dotnet restore, the build still fails because it claims there are no files in that directory.  What small step am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I was right, it was a small thing.

Instead of using COPY C:/PATH/to/packages/*.dll, use /packages/*.dll, where /packages is a folder within the one hosting the .csproj.